# Why I am getting different results while executing the following command with cmd and git bash?

Tags: java, git, bash, maven, cmd

While I am executing the command below, I have BUILD SUCCESS in git bash and BUILD FAILURE in cmd. Why do I have such a differnce? Do I need to execute this in git bash only or did I miss anything? Thank you.

`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.1`

```
C:\Users\tabma\Desktop\Jersey>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jer
sey-quickstart-grizzly2 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -Dint
eractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactID=simple-service -Dpackage=c
om.example -DarchetypeVersion=2.1
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources
@ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources
@ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom --
-
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [org.glassfish.jerse
y.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-grizzly2:2.17] found in catalog remote
[WARNING] Property artifactId is missing. Add -DartifactId=someValue
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.394 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-22T18:08:38-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.3:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Archetype org.glassfish.jer
sey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-grizzly2:2.1 is not configured
[ERROR] Property artifactId is missing.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

This is the same command but using git bash

```
TABMA@TABMA-PC ~/Desktop/Jersey
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 -Darc
hetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId
=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example -DarchetypeVersi
on=2.1
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources
@ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources
@ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom -
-
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [org.glassfish.jers
y.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-grizzly2:2.17] found in catalog remote
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype
 jersey-quickstart-grizzly2:2.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.example
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: com.example
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.example
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: simple-service
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: C:\Users\ta4java\Desktop\Jersey
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: C:\Users\ta4java\Deskto
\Jersey\simple-service
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.972 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-22T22:36:34-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/28M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There are any number of possible reasons why running `mvn` from a Windows CMD prompt *might* fail.  What error messages do you get?

Comment: I was trying to upload the screen shot....

Comment: I think I need 10 reputations to upload an image right? Anyways I editedd my post; added the error from cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capitalization matters, you're setting value `-DartifactID=simple-service` but it's saying that `-DartifactId` isn't set.  Note the difference in capitalization on "Id".

Comment: I really thank you for that. I was not able to figure out what was wrong with it. Now it is working fine with cmd.